# How to mark file as already encrypted

Tags: java, encryption

I am trying to implement a simple encryption utility for educational pourpuses, it works, at least with simple files, but when I succesfully encrypt one file, i'd like not to encrypt it again, because that could lead to loose my data if i encrypt/decrypt it in a wrong way... Is there a way to prevent me from do it?

I am using java, and the default encryption library.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you encrypt it again? I mean, what is the scenario you want to avoid, otherwise there's no point in it.

Comment: Have you created your own application to encrypt these files?  or are you using a 3rd party tool?  Assuming the scenario your trying to avoid is that every time you run the encryption on a folder it just picks every file up in the folder and encrypts them again?

Comment: @shawty yes, that's the scenario, the idea is to avoid to pick up already encrypted file once again

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo I would encrypt the file again by error... since this is a cli utility

Comment: @jaxkodex - in that case then scenario 1 in my answer is likely to suit you.  I can't give you an exact answer as it depends on your OS, but it really shouldn't be difficult to create some kind of shell/command script that will automate the process for you.

Comment: @shawty sorry for not clarifying it before, i am coding it, so i have access to the source code.

Comment: AH, well that's ok then... ignore my Approach 1   :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to what you want to know here depends very much on how your encrypting the files in the first place.

I'll list a couple of different approaches that might help you however

### Approach 1 - Scripting

If your using a 3rd party tool such as an encryption util written by another java programmer, and if your running this tool in some kind of a shell session, your best bet might be to wrap the invocation of said tool in a shell script.

If your running on windows this could be a batch file, on Linux a bash script.

Essentially you use this approach by working out ahead of time what command you need to use, then putting that command into said shell script while substituting any parameters you need to change.

Following on from the wrapped command you could then provide further commands to rename the file, or embed some kind of information in it's file properties or file name, a possible example might be something like:

```
IF NOT EXIST %%0.encrypted(
  encrypt %%0 -a -b -c -d
  rename %%0 %%0.encrypted) ELSE (
)
ELSE
()
```

***NOTE: These are just theoretical examples as I don't know what your OS is***

If this was saved in a file called 'myencrypt.bat', then you could just type

```
myencrypt.bat afile.ext
```

### Approach 2 - Custom Bytes

If you have direct control of the source code and consequently the application that performs this encryption, then why not make a pseudo file format.

Add some kind of a marker into the file that your program then checks for.

By way of an example, you could perhaps

add the following string to the front of the file

```
ENCFOriginalFile.Ext
```

Turn that into a set of bytes, then load the file in, encrypt it, add the bytes from the text on and save it back out, maybe with a custom file extension.

When you come to encrypt a file again, all you then need to do is read the first 4 bytes and if they are equal to **ENCF** you know that the file is already encrypted.

Those are just 2 ideas I can think of off the top of my head, but it's late here and I'm tired.  If I was more awake I could probably come up with a whole page full.

Comment: I like the second approach better, how can i add these bits if i am moving the result from a tmp (encrypted) file to the original file overwritting it using file streams.

Comment: If you have a stream open (And bear in mind I don't do much Java These days :-) ) then the best way would be just to open a second stream for output.  In theory, you'd open a stream, write the bytes representing the header, then open the second stream on the tmp file and just pipe the second stream into the first.  As for checking the file when the encryption app start's up, well it's only the first four bytes, so you don't really need a stream for that, you can get away with reading a 32 bit integer then closing the file again.

Comment: If you don't have control of the sources, then TBH I'm not to sure how you might do it.  I know under windows you can do a "copy /b file1+file2 file3", that would take file1 and file2 concatenate them at a binary level and save the result in file3, but you still need to generate the header somehow.

Answer (score -1):

Since it is encrypted it cannot be opened in the default program for that file type, so you can savely rename the file. This can be done for example by adding `.enc` as the extension. Doing so will make it easy to spot the encrypted file for you and your java application.

Depending on your use case you can also let your java application manage a database of encrypted files.

Comment: how could i keep this tool portable, so that i could just take the jar and use it where ever i want with java, i guess i could use a sqllite database but i'd have to have that db always. I guess moving the file to a new extension would be the best aproach. but i'd have to delete the previous one.

Comment: The database can stay in a hidden folder right with your encrypted files. Yes, you will have to delete the previous one in that case. Depending on the size of the files that you want to encrypt, you may not be able to encrypt the data inplace, because that would require to read the file completely into memory. Inplace encryption is not easy to do, but has the advantage that you don't really need to secure erase the unencrypted file.